# jq sort and remove duplicates from output

Tags: json, sorting, jq, unique

I have following json structure

```
  { 
     "root": {
       "elements": [
           {
             "id": "abcd"
           },
           {
             "id": "efgh"
           },
           {
             "id": "abcd"
           }
       ]
     }
  }
```

I need to dump values of id fields, alphabetically sorted and without duplicates.

desired output:

```
abcd
efgh
```

`jq '.root.elements[].id'` - will dump me data i need

i found 'unique' jq command should do both - sorting and removing duplicates - but after some testing i found out that it requires an array of strings/numbers but here im working with array of objects instead

i would like to have this os independent, i cannot use unix utlities like sort and unique

Comment: You can use `jq '[.root.elements[].id] | unique | .[]'`

Comment: Or `jq '.root.elements | map(.id) | unique[]'`

Answer (score 2):

`unique` works with complex objects too and does not require simple strings. Thus, you can simple dedupe the objects in the array, then stream their ids:

```
.root.elements | unique[].id
```

Note that `unique[].id` is just shorthand for `unique[] | .id` which in turn is shorthand for `unique | .[] | .id`.

---

Alternatively, [`map`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)) the array to a new array consisting only of ids, dedupe and then stream:

```
.root.elements | map(.id) | unique[]
```